# Simple Scala Parser

Tags: scala, parser-generator

Using the `scala.util.parsing.combinator._` package, how can I create a simple `Parser` that will match on `abc`?

Example:

```
val parser = new Parser("abc")
val stream: Stream[Character] = Stream('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')   
println("parser(stream) : " + parser(stream))`
```

prints out:

> Success(('a', 'b', 'c'), Stream('d'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivial:

```
object MyParsers extends scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers {
  val parser: Parser[String] = "abc"
  // or more explicit: val parser = literal("abc")
}
```

However, you may need a `Stream[Char]` instead of a `Stream[Character]`.

You can also use `acceptSeq("abc")`, since `String` is implicitly convertable to `Iterable[Char]`, but it will be significantly less efficient.

Comment: After running `import scala.util.parsing.combinator._` from REPL, I tried `scala> val parser: Parser[String] = "abc"
<console>:10: error: not found: type Parser
       val parser: Parser[String] = "abc"
                   ^`

Comment: You need to extend `scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Alexey. And, to test it out: `parser("abcdef")` returning `Success`, I'd need to create an instance of `scala.util.parsing.input.Reader()`?